# How to select a logical expressions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I simply want to select a boolean value that indicates something like the following ...

```
select name , age > 18 from tbl_user ;
```

it gives an error on the expression  `age > 18`

Can anyone just tell me how can I add expressions in the select query ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select name, case when age > 18
                  then 'ok'
                  else 'not ok'
             end as age_ok
from tbl_user
```

Instead of `ok` and `not ok` you can use `1` and `0` for boolean values if you like

Answer (score 1):

```
select name , case when age>18 then 1 else 0 end from tbl_user ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t table (
    Name varchar(max),
    Age int
)

insert @t(Name, Age)
    values ('David', 27),
    ('Anna', 52),
    ('Joseph', 17)

select Name, Age, case when Age > 18 then 1 else 0 end from @t
```